# Workarounds for "cp -p" not preserving nanoseconds on High Sierra with APFS?

Tags: command-line, high-sierra, apfs

I don't know if this affects MacOS versions newer than High Sierra, but it seems that `cp -p` won't preserve timestamps with nanoseconds resolution.

Because of this, the shell can wrongly tell that a file is older than other even if it was copied by `cp -p`. This breaks build system dependencies when some files were installed by `cp -p`: they keep reinstalling and reinstalling again because the nanoseconds don't match.

Can you suggest some workaround for this? I thought compiling my own `cp` binary, but however `cp` is usually a shell builtin, and moreover I'm not aware of any nanosecond-preserving `cp` version out there.

**Note:** I know of a workaround, but it's not reasonable: Execute `touch` on the source file before executing `cp -p`. Because `touch` doesn't preserve nanoseconds either, it makes them zero on the source file, so the result after `cp -p` guarantees exactly the same timestamp. However, as I said, it's not reasonable, because I don't like to `touch` files just for this: you lose their real last saved date.

Answer (score 3):

Good to know that I'm not the only one who thinks this is a problem. I ran into it while writing a Python script for monitoring parts of my macOS (10.15.7) filesystem, which also involved coping files. [The script sometimes behaved erratic and produced unpredictable output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63983742/why-does-shutil-copy2-sometimes-modify-the-files-st-mtime). After some poking around I found out that the incapability of `cp -p` to preserve nanoseconds is the core of the problem.

One workaround for your problem (but not for mine) could be [`coreutils`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/coreutils): `gcp -p` behaves as intended.

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was fixed in 10.15, but I just didn't repro the problem correctly. To save others the same embarrassment, here's a repro that shows the problem:

```
% python3 -c 'open("file1", "w")'
% stat -f %Fm file1
1609301645.481666557
% cp -p file1 file2
% stat -f %Fm file2
1609301645.481666000
```

Comment: aren't the listed numbers short of a nanosecond accuracy.  Nanosecond = 10^-9.  listed decimals are 10^-6.

Comment: You're right! I thought it copying sub-second timestamp info was good news, but it isn't. I edited my "answer".

Comment: I also filed a feedback report: https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4946596567449600 I'd recommend everyone who wants this fixed to also file a report at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/